# Safely converting between 2 templates classes with common base

Tags: c++, templates, casting

Consider the following

```
template<typename T>
struct Wrapper{ T t; };

template<typename T>
struct Variant1 : public Wrapper< T >
{
    // ... Member types, static members, non virtual functions ... //
}

template<typename T>
struct Variant2 : public Wrapper< T >
{
    // ... Member types, static members, non virtual functions ... //
}
```

Is there a way to convert for example `Variant1<int> &` to `Variant2<int> &` without triggering UB. I've searched SO for answers but most questions related to this are of the form "Is it safe to do it this specific way". My question is there any safe way to do this.

Some ways I found are:

- direct cast: `( Variant2< int > & ) value` or the same using `reinterpret_cast`
- cast to `Wrapper<int> &` and then into `Variant2<int> &`

**Edit**

Specific Example:

```
Variant1< int > val{ .t = 5 };
Variant2< int > & ref = ?Convert?( val );
```

Goal:

The goal would be to be able to create "Tagged" types which simply act as a proxy around the wrapped type and would prevent accidental mixing of two different tags. However sometimes it is necessary to explicitly convert from one tag to another. This should be a compile time thing, and thus not really cause any overhead.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish with this?  There is one possible way but it depends on exactly what you want to do.

Comment: Depends on the actual type. If your `Variant1&` actually refers to a `Variant1` complete object, then definitely no (unless you never actually evaluate (lvalue-to-rvalue) the resulting reference). Also I don't see how `T` is relevant here, at all.

Comment: you can write a converting constructor.

Comment: In general, it will be **UB**.  There may be a specific & narrow use-case where it is well-defined, but that does not appear to be the case in the limited example provided.

Comment: With your example, everything option you listed in the question is UB (unless you never actually use `ref`), assuming that you did not write any conversion operator yourself.

Comment: What is wrong with [std::variant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) ?

Comment: regarding your edit, it does not seem like the few workarounds will work in this case.  You might be best off just doing a copy from one type to the other.

Comment: If that is a tag it should be thin wrapper around `T` so it should be not a problem to get `T` from `Variant1` and construct `Variant2` in a helper function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to convert for example `Variant1<int> &` to `Variant2<int> &` without triggering UB

No. It also defeats the whole point of your polymorphism if you're just reinterpreting one derived class as another.
What is the point of `Wrapper` then, and why couldn't you just use `std::any`?

> The goal would be to be able to create "Tagged" types which simply act as a proxy around the wrapped type and would prevent accidental mixing of two different tags.

This sounds like `Wrapper` should contain `T` and also a separate tag type as a member.
Alternatively, a `std::variant<Variant1<int>, Variant2<int>>` might make sense, if every `VariantX` can be constructed from a `Wrapper`.
In such a case, you could use `std::visit` to obtain any "tagged type" you want.

In any case, you haven't provided enough details for a full solution.